# Erlang: get ip address from hostname

Tags: networking, erlang, ip, hostname

In my local network exists pcs, where have a hostname as example "testhost". How can I from given hostname get a IP-address ?

I tried:

```
net_adm:dns_hostname("testhost.fritz.box").
```

Result:

```
{ok,"testhost.fritz.box"}
```

I need a function which give me IP-Address from hostname.

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#getaddr-2 it seems you should be able to use `getaddr` like:

```
inet:getaddr("testhost.fritz.box", inet)
```

Comment: In Elixir code, you can call this like `"testhost.fritz.box" |> String.to_charlist() |> :inet.getaddr(:inet)`. (The regular Elixir string literals seem to result in an `einval` error.